# Apache 2.2 htaccess Require Password and IP Address

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2.2

In htaccess using Apache 2.2.x, is there a way to require a password and a certain IP address, and block outright everyone else?

I've tried all the Allow/Deny/Require/Satisfy combinations I could find or try. Maybe someone here has the answer? I did an extensive search but everyone is looking to allow bypassing a password for certain IP addresses, not demanding an IP and password.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you want to block the ip directly from the server and not through an app?

Comment: Yes, this is a pre-authorization setup to allow access to a WordPress wp-login.php file. Currently I have it set up to require a login/password in Apache before people get to the wordpress login, to block WP brute force attacks, but for some domains I want to restrict it even further to just my IP address.

Comment: As a side note... I did find a way to accomplish this but not just using Apache. I use nginx (running as a proxy) to block all but certain IP addresses before passing the proxy through to Apache which then requires the password. Problem solved, kinda.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest setting up your configuration to require just a password first, and once you have that working as intended. Add the correct `allow from` directive to the `htaccess` file. For example

```
Allow from 192.168.0.0
```

You should not need to add anything else as `Satisfy All` is the default, but if you are still having problems add this as well.

If you are still having problems show us the `htaccess` file and check the rest of your config for overriding configuration.

New config based on discussion below:

```
<Location />
  Order allow,deny
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Restricted Files"
  AuthBasicProvider file
  AuthUserFile /path/to/htpasswd
  Require valid-user
  Satisfy all
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>
```

Additional info, doesn't need the `<Location>` block if in htaccess

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work since it works off a first rule wins method. You can't both require an IP address and a Password... it only allows one or the other. My solution works fine though of using nginx with it.

Comment: It does work, and I've used it several times myself. The whole point of `Satisfy All` is to allow you to require multiple conditions for authorisation/authentication. If your configuration is not working then you have either done it wrong or you have conflicting configuration somewhere. The fact that you have it working in nginx suggests your distro distributes initial apache configuration files which are "broken" in some way.

Comment: I think you'll find it doesn't work if you are denying everyone except one IP, and also require a password from that IP. Everyone except that IP should be denied without a password prompt. Using Satisfy All in the case where you are denying everyone gives them a password prompt instead of denying them. Therefore, using Satisfy All will not work in this case. This is why I said "...block outright everyone else" in my question... "everyone else" should not even get a password prompt. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Just added a config to my answer that does what you require. Someone not from 127.0.0.1  gets denied immediately, otherwise asked for a password. If I've misunderstood, please elaborate.

Comment: Hey that works!
I've been using it to try and add security to a <Files wp-login.php> block and for some reason it doesn't work inside that, but it does in a location block.  Hmm.....

Comment: `<LocationMatch>` maybe what you need then. If you having problems with the configuration in a `<Files>` block it may be a merging problem. You can read about merging here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/sections.html#mergin